# Angular Filter Functionality

Tags: angularjs, select, filter, dropdown

I need to have these two dropdown filters speak to each other so both are filtered when either are selected:

```
<div>                 
  <div class="table-single-row select-list">
    <div>
      <select name="citiesSelected" id="citiesSelected" ng-change="citySelected(citiesSelected)" ng-model="citiesSelected"  >
        <option value="" ng-selected=true>All regions</option>
        <option ng-repeat="city in cities | unique: 'group'" value="{{city.group}}">{{city.group}}</option>
      </select>                
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="taxonomySelected" id="taxonomySelected" ng-change="fieldSelected(taxonomySelected)" ng-model="taxonomySelected" >
        <option value="" ng-selected=true>All sectors</option>
        <option ng-repeat="field in fields" value="{{field.name}}">{{field.name}}</option>
      </select> 
    </div>
  </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously misunderstand your question, here i can only provide the idea due to time limits.

```
funciton filterByConditions() {
    //Do you logic to filter result by both $scope.condition1 and $scope.condition2
}

onSelect1Change(condition1) {
    $scope.condition1 = condition1;
    filterByConditions();
}

onSelect2Change(condition2) {
    $scope.condition2 = condition2;
    filterByConditions();
}
```